# innerHTML should contain a dynamic variable

Tags: angular

In my code, I have to use [innerHTML] and inject some HTML that I'm getting from the backend. I can't change this approach.

I need to set a dynamic `alt` attribute on this injectable HTML.

My front-end HTML:

```
<div
    class="product-badge-container"
    *ngFor="let badge of myProduct?.badgesWithIcon | slice: 0:3"
  >
    <div *ngIf="badge.badge_html">
      <div
        [innerHtml]="badge.badge_html | safeHtml"
        class="badge-icon"
        (click)="badgeClicked(badge)"
        tabindex="0"
      ></div>
      <span *ngIf="isHorizontalView">{{ badge | badgeLabel }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**badge.badge_html** is basically the following:

```
    <img src="https://link_to_my_img.jpg"></img>
```

I thought to add a function to my front-end component that will be called when rendering the injectable HTML.

The component will have this function:

```
  productBadgeAriaLabel(badge) {
    return `${badge.group_label ? badge.group_label : badge.group_name} group item`;
  }
```

and the injectable HTML will have a hardcoded `alt` attribute:

```
    <img [alt]="productBadgeAriaLabel(badge)" src="https://link_to_my_img.jpg"></img>
```

The idea was that while rendering the page the HTML will be injected and will call the function. But this trick didn't work (I thought the change detector would solve this).

Do you have any ideas on how to solve it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending inner html from the API,

```
<img [alt]="productBadgeAriaLabel(badge)" src="https://link_to_my_img.jpg"></img>
```

this makes no sense because the function is not gonna bind to template in that manner

Try the flowing approach,

First, add a custom data attribute to the div,(let's say data-alt).
Set your alt value to it using your function

```
<div
   [attr.data-alt]="productBadgeAriaLabel(badge)"
   [innerHtml]="badge.badge_html | safeHtml"
   class="badge-icon"
   (click)="badgeClicked(badge)"
   tabindex="0"
></div>
```

Then create a function in the component to grab that div and set alt to inside img element.

```
  setAlts() {
    const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('badge-icon');
    for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      const element = elements[i];
      const altText = element.getAttribute('data-alt') || '';
      const imgElement = element.getElementsByTagName('img');
      if (imgElement.length > 0) {
        imgElement[0].alt = altText;
      }
    }
  }
```

Finally, call setAlts() function after receiving the successful API response.
If you get an error or not working correctly, try calling setAlts() function inside a setTimeout

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.setAlts();
});
```

NOTE: you need to call this after you get a successful response.

NOTE: If you want, you can keep a separate Map inside the component to get relevant alt values instead of adding it to a data-* property.